# Unable to choose scale for each monitor - Fedora v30

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, fedora

I'm running Fedora v30 on an X1 Carbon ThinkPad and having basic issues with configuring a single dual monitor connected through HDMI.
The [display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsCHR.png) give an option for scale on each monitor however only the built-in display scale changes what happens on both screens (despite having an apparent option for each screen).

Ideally I would like the built-in display to be at 200% and the dual monitor at 100%, otherwise the menu/toolbars are very large/small on each screen. Fedora doesn't seem to give many options for changing this kind of thing and I'm not sure how else to tweak it.  Am I missing something? How to manually resize toolbar and menu bar size on Fedora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to configure with:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1 --pos 160x1620
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 1.5x1.5 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 3840x4200 --pos 0x0
```

with internal monitor 2560x1440 and external of 1920x1080. Icons are still blurry but manageable overall.